# Composite/sobjects API without referenceId - which record is which?

Tags: rest-api

I can create multiple records using `/services/data/v46.0/composite/sobjects` API.

Unfortunately, the response does not handle `referenceId` the same way as the `stree` API does.

So when i try this payload:

```
{"allOrNone":true,
"records":[
{"attributes":{"type":"Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},"name":"SampleAccount1"},
{"attributes":{"type":"Account", "referenceId" : "ref2"},"name":"SampleAccount2"}
]}
```

I get a simple

```
[{"id":"SomeId1","success":true,"errors":[]},{"id":"SomeId2","success":true,"errors":[]}]
```

Looking at the data in the UI it seems that SampleAccount1 is the first id, and `2` is the second.

However, i can't find any documentation confirming that this is guaranteed.

Considering the API works in batches of up to 200, how are you meant to marry up those ids back to the original records you sent (unless you somehow use external Ids which is not always the case for all objects).

Comment: can you post a link to the stree api? I can't find any docs referencing it.

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm) states:

> Objects are created in the order they’re listed. The SaveResult objects are returned in the order in which the create requests were specified.

As such, we do have a documented guarantee that the order will be preserved.

Comment: What's confusing is that in the composite api and in SObject Tree APIs we are offered the option to provide 'referenceId' to map this exactly. This leads me to believe that the order may not be guaranteed for those, but the SObject Collections API is a bit vague on that, yet it (in theory) can suffer from the same issues as the other two.

Comment: @zaitsman Actually, referenceId is meant to be used to be able to link a record to another record (e.g. you can insert an account and contact, referencing the contact AccountId field to the account you just created). This particular resource still returns records in the order they were created, such as index 0 of the request is returned as index 0 of the response. The tree API needs to return referenceId values because the children will be returned out of order in respect to their parents.

Comment: @zaitsman And... I found it in the docs after all. See edit.

Comment: Thanks heaps @sfdcfox, i was looking at the very same doco page and totally missed that somehow